# Latent class growth modelling in R/flexmix with multinomial outcome variable

Tags: r, factors, multinomial, model-fitting

1. How to run Latent Class Growth Modelling (LCGM) with a multinomial response variable in R (using the flexmix package)?
2. And how to stratify each class by a binary/categorical dependent variable?

The idea is to let gender shape the growth curve by cluster (cf. [Mikolai and Lyons-Amos (2017, p. 194/3)](http://llcsjournal.org/index.php/llcs/article/view/415) where the stratification is done by education. They used Mplus)

I think I might have come close with the following syntax:

```
lcgm_formula <- as.formula(rel_stat~age + I(age^2) + gender + gender:age)
lcgm <- flexmix::stepFlexmix(.~ .| id,
                         data=d,
                         k=nr_of_classes,       # would be 1:12 in real analysis
                         nrep=1,                # would be 50 in real analysis to avoid local maxima
                         control = list(iter.max = 500, minprior = 0),
                         model = flexmix::FLXMRmultinom(lcgm_formula,varFix=T,fixed = ~0))
```

,which is close to what [Wardenaar (2020,p. 10)](https://psyarxiv.com/m58wx/) suggests in his methodological paper for a continuous outcome:

```
stepFlexmix(.~ .|ID, k = 1:4,nrep = 50, model = FLXMRglmfix(y~ time, varFix=TRUE), data = mydata, control = list(iter.max = 500, minprior = 0))
```

The only difference is that the `FLXMRmultinom` probably does not support `varFix` and `fixed` parameters, altough adding them *do* produce different results. The binomial equivalent for `FLXMRmultinom` in flexmix might be `FLXMRglm` (with family="binomial") as opposed `FLXMRglmfix` so I suspect that the restrictions of the LCGM (eg. fixed slope & intercept per class) are not specified they way it should.

The results are otherwise sensible, but model fails to put men and women with similar trajectories in the same classes (below are the fitted probabilities for each relationship status in each class by gender):

[image]

We should have the following matches by cluster and gender...

```
1<->1
2<->2
3<->3
```

...but instead we have

```
1<->3
2<->1
3<->2
```

That is, if for example men in class one and women in class three would be forced in the same group, the created group would be more similar than the current first row of the plot grid.

[Here is the full MVE](https://gist.github.com/samuelsaari/59cba7a997c36024b07c502253c3ac90) to reproduce the code.

Got similar results with another dataset with diffent number of classes and up to 50 iterations/class. Have tried two alternative ways to predict the probabilities, with identical results. I conclude that the problem is most likely in the model specification (`stepflexmix(...,model=FLXMRmultinom(...`) or this is some sort of label switch issue.

If the model would be specified correctly and the issue is that similar trajectories for men/women end up in different classes, is there a way to fix that? By for example restricting the parameters?

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a an identifiability issue apparently common in mixture modelling. In other words the labels are switched so that while there might not be a problem with the modelling as such, men and women end up in different groups and that will have to be dealt with one way or another

In the the [new linked code](https://gist.github.com/samuelsaari/4b198274aabadf2f6061080973789d7c), I have swapped the order manually and calculated the predictions with by hand.

**Will be happy to hear, should someone has an alternative approach to deal with the label swithcing issue** (like restricting parameters or switching labels algorithmically).  Also curious if the model could/should be specified in some other way.

A few remarks:

- I believe that this is indeed performing a LCGM as we do not specify random effects for the slopes or intercepts. Therefore I assume that intercepts and slopes are fixed within classes for both sexes. That would mean that the model performs LCGM as intended. By the same token, it seems that running GMM with random intercept, slope or both is not possible.
- Since we are calculating the predictions by hand, we need to be able to separate parameters between the sexes. Therefore I also added an interaction term `gender x age^2`. The calculations seems to slow down somewhat, but the estimates are similar to the original. It also makes conceptually sense to include the interaction for age^2 if we have it for age already.
- `varFix=T,fixed = ~0` seem to be reduntant: specifying them do not change anything. The  subsampling procedure (of my real data) was unaffected by the `set.seed()` command for some reason.

The new model specification becomes:

```
lcgm_formula <- as.formula(rel_stat~ age + I(age^2) +gender + age:gender + I(age^2):gender)
lcgm <- flexmix::flexmix(.~ .| id,
                         data=d,
                         k=nr_of_classes, # would be 1:12 in real analysis
                         #nrep=1, # would be 50 in real analysis to avoid local maxima (and we would use the stepFlexmix function instead)
                         control = list(iter.max = 500, minprior = 0),
                         model = flexmix::FLXMRmultinom(lcgm_formula))
```

And the plots:
[image]

[image]